# NTP does not sync over IPv6

Tags: debian, ipv6, ntp

I deployed an NTP server on Debian 8.5 with the following hosts:

```
server time1.example.com
server time2.example.com
---
server time5.example.com
```

`time5` is an ipv6-only host.

Further down the config, I have

```
restrict -6 1:1:1:::1 kod noquery nopeer nomodify notrap

# Local users may interrogate the ntp server more closely.
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

# Restrict everything else
restrict default ignore
```

When I run `ntpq -p`, it shows me

```
 time5.example.com .INIT.  16 u - 512 0 0.000 0.000 0.000
```

Is there something wrong in my config? I ran an `ip6tables -L` command and there are no rules, and it's set to allow.

IPv6 is enabled on the host. It's on Digital Ocean.

Comment: It is a good idea to paste your entire config. You are probably not the best judge of what is relevant, if you were, you would not be posting this question. Please post entire config, and what commands you have used to verify connectivity to the ipv6 timeserver. finally you realize your example restrict line uses an ipv4 address?

Comment: IPv4 is working fine. I'm only having issues with IPv6 for NTP.

Comment: You are looking for help but you failed to address any of my comments and questions; you simply restates tour question. Why would people want to take time out of their day to help when you behave like this?

Comment: @debianuse1 1.1.1.1 is not an IPv6 address.  Try default instead.

Comment: Your edited address, `1:1:1:::1` is not a valid IPv6 address.

Comment: I used it as an example.

Comment: Also, I can ping6 IP_ADDR and ping6 HOST_NAME from the host and it works.